# How to convert a AssetEntity type to File Type?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I am trying to assign the assets.first to image variable. But I am getting the error "A value of type 'AssetEntity' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File?'".

```
          GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {
                 
                            setState(() {
                              image = assets.first;
                            });
                          },
                          child: FittedBox(
                            child: AssetEntityImage(assets.first),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
```

I tried to typeconvert but that didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert an AssetEntity to a File type in Flutter, you can use the file method provided by the AssetEntity class. This method asynchronously returns a File object representing the asset.

Here's how you can modify your code to assign the AssetEntity to a File variable:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () async {
        File? file = await assets.first.file; // Retrieve the File from the AssetEntity
        setState(() {
            image = file; // Assign the File to your image variable
        });
    },
    child: FittedBox(
        child: AssetEntityImage(assets.first),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
);
```

In this code snippet, assets.first.file is an asynchronous call that returns a Future. You need to wait for this Future to complete using await to get the File object. Then, you can assign this File object to your image variable.

Make sure that the onTap function is marked as async since you're using await within it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: @MarkJohn Considering this answer is AI-generated (plagiarized), it will very likely be deleted in the near future. I would suggest posting your own answer explaining *exactly* what solved your problem in your own words and accepting that instead so that your question still has an answer after this one is gone.